Distances distributions in 2D Klein bottle universe
Suppose we're living in a Klein bottle universe that's obtained by gluing a 2×4 rectangle with a flip along the edge of length 2. Where can we expect to find the peaks in the distances distribution between large-scale structure objects (think galaxies clusters)?
If it were a torus (so no flips), then the answer seems easy: it's $\sqrt{(2i)^2 + (4j)^2},$ where $i, j \in \mathbb{N}, i + j > 0$ — we get a peak at $2$ by looking parallel to the short edge, a peak at $4$ by looking parallel to the long edge, $\sqrt{2^2 + 4^2}$ by looking parallel to a "diagonal", and so on.
Then, since two flips cancel out in a sense, by similar reasoning I expect to find peaks in the Klein bottle at $\sqrt{(2i)^2 + ((4 + 4)j)^2}$ — that's a subset of the previous one, resulting from looking through an even number of flips. But are there more, corresponding to an odd number of flips?
My intuition says "no", since it depends on a particular distribution within the rectangle — objects close to the center line of the rectangle will have distances between their "copies" almost unaffected, while objects close to the long side of the rectangle will shift considerably. But is that the case?

As well as your $\sqrt{(2i)^2 + (8j)^2}$ I would have thought you might have $\sqrt{(2i+1)^2 + (8j+4)^2}$ $\big($including $\sqrt{1^2+4^2}\big)$.

Hmm, I'm not sure I can see where this one comes from. If those are the diagonals, then won't they have the same problem as I mentioned for the odd number of flips?
